# How to add unique materials in duplicated bodies?

Tags: materials

I duplicated a football player but when I wanted to work in only one of them the changes of materials happend to both of them ! Please tell me how to work on materials seperatly !!!

Comment: Just add a new material in the player you're editing. Make the material you want and then deselect everything in editmode, click on the material it currently has and which you plan to change, click select in the materials tab, click on the new material you added, click assign and delete the old material.